# jquery form IE9 file upload not firing callbacks

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, file-upload

I'm trying to post a file to an external service with the following implementation:

JS:

```
$("#formFile").ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit:  prepareRequest, 
    success:       showResponse,
    error:         showErr
});

function prepareRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    console.log(formData);
}

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
    console.log(responseText);
}

function showErr(data, a, c) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(a);
    console.log(c);
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="/destiny" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formFile">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I'm having problems in IE9. Since the jquery form plugin uses the iFrame method to upload file in older browsers, when the browser gets the server's response I get a "Download file" prompt and neither "success" nor "error" callbacks are fired.

I have no control in the server's response so I cannot force the Content-Type to  be `text/html` as [the documentation suggests](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload)